# How to Create a new metric in google data studio with count specific term in field

Tags: regex, google-analytics, looker-studio, re2

I've a field with tow distinct string `foo` and `bar`. I want to create a new calculated metrics based on this field where I only count the number of `foo` string. how do I do that ?

So far I've tried this but doesn't work :

`COUNT(CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(type,'foo.*'))`

Not sure if my question is clear. please tell me if it's not.

Edit : I found this solution `SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` however I would love to know how to solve this issue with Regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/360suite/datastudio/answer/7064476?hl=en) requires a full string match:

> `REGEXP_MATCH` attempts to match the entire string contained in *field_expression*. For example, if field_expression is "ABC123":
>   `REGEXP_MATCH(field_expression, 'A')` returns false.
>   `REGEXP_MATCH(field_expression, 'A.*')` returns true.

Thus, to find a string containing `foo`, use

```
REGEXP_MATCH(type,'.*foo.*')
```